# Print doesn't work in MS Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I tried

```
fileNum = FreeFile
Open "c:\test.txt" For Output As fileNum 
Print fileNum , "test"
Close fileNum
```

It says it's not supported whereas VBA help says it's supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why but you have to include the `#` symbol

```
 Print #fileNum, "test"
```